# Proof of inequality of 'bernoulli' weighted components

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think this is true but I am not sure how to show it.

If we have that $A \leq \alpha B + (1 - \alpha) C$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$.

Prove that $A$ is strictly less than $\text{min}\{B,C\}$

Comment: Do you mean "for any $\alpha$" or "for some $\alpha$"?

Comment: Take $A=B=C$. $B < B$?

Comment: @mfl for any alpha between 0 and 1

Comment: To clarify Clement C's point: $A \leq \alpha B+(1-\alpha)C=\alpha A+(1-\alpha)A=A$. $A<min \{B, C\}=A$ is a contradiction. In fact, $A<max \{B, C\}=A$ would also be a contradiction.